# How to implement proximity search for latitude and longitude values?

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, hash, approximation

my application (Qt based mobile application) gets data from a server in the following format : latitude,longitude,description.

I need to store this data in a data structure for quick retrieval later. Now i have a map and when the user clicks on a point in the map i get the latitude,longitude of that point. Using these 2 values i needly quickly scan my data structure and retrieve the associated description. My problem is..that the latitude and longitude i get on clicking in the map is an approximation (its a touch device so i never get the exact lat +long), so if i do a linear search on the data structure i never find these values. Besides, if there is too much data, a linear search will be very slow.

1. What data structure should i use to store lat+long+description ( a hash comes to my mind..but i have no clue how to combine long+lat to form a key)
2. How do i do an approximative search on the data structure?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The data-structure you are looking for is a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree). If you really want hashing, and some small error is acceptable, you could look into [this paper(pdf)](http://www.cs.bu.edu/groups/dblab/pub_pdfs/athitsos_icde2008.pdf), which describes an approach for distance based hashing.

You will have to try which one works better for you. I implemented the algorithm in that paper, and it did not work well for my problem (probably because my data-points were not very evenly distributed). This might be different in your case, so you will have to try.

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem consists of only 2 dimensions we can use a binary tree. Where each leaf can have maximum of "N" points (consider latitude,longitude as a point).Only leaf nodes will have points.

Data type of point

```
class Point
{
  float Latitude;
  float Longitude;
  string Description;
}
```

Data type of  Internal Node (NonLeaf Node)

```
class Node
{
   Float MaxLatitude;
   Float MinLatitude;
   Float MaxLongitude;
   Float MinLongitude;
}
```

Data type of leafnode

```
class LeafNode
{
   Point points[K]; // Array of points
}
```

Generate the Binary tree dynamically and divide the node as you insert more points .If the height of the node is even then divide it based on latitude else divide based on longitude.

When searching for a input point find the relevant leaf node and all the points in that leaf node will be closest points to the input point.

This is a popular problem - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximate_nearest_neighbor